# How to fix error: "The URI segment 'notebooks' is invalid after the segment 'notes'"

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I'm trying to get information about a OneNote notebook that is stored in CRM. Using the CRM api, I can fetch OneNote notebook ids, which I should be able to send to the OneNote api to get its contents. However, when I send a request I get the error: "The OData query is invalid. The URI segment 'notebooks' is invalid after the segment 'notes'."

I have to request a Bearer Access token, and I made an application which has the permission: Notes.Read.All, which should enable me to have access to read OneNote books across the organization.

The following url seems to say that my request should be valid syntax. Perhaps I'm using an incorrect site id or something?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-list-notebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0

The bearer token is able to fetch information about a user's specific OneNote books with no issues, but I need to be able to fetch by the site where they are stored.

My request looks like the following (numbers and letter placed by me): 
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/aaaaaaaa-5555-4444-bbbb-g7g8g9g10/onenote/notebooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site Id has to be specified in a 3 part (separated by 2 commas) like format. See it's documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Thanks!

Comment: Cool. I understand the initial sharepoint origin, do you happen to know what the difference is between the two identifiers? Is one the parent location and the other the actual id or something?

Comment: Found it. The pattern is {origin}/{sitecollectionid}/{documentid}. I'm running into an issue where the files I'm trying to get are located somewhere not on the origin, but my request is currently working, thanks!